# How to access nested lists through for loops

Tags: python-3.x, list

So I am trying to learn how to do web scraping. Im having some issues though. I don't know how to scrape from other websites as each one is different where should I go for more practice?

```
import bs4 as bs
import datetime as dt
import os
#import yfinance as yf
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
#yf.pdr_override()
#import pandas_datareader.data as web
import pickle
import requests

def save_sp500_tickers():

    return tickers

#save_sp500_tickers()

def get_data_from_yahoo(reload_sp500=False):

    if reload_sp500:
        tickers = save_sp500_tickers()
    else:
        with open("sp500tickers.pickle", "rb") as f:
            tickers = pickle.load(f)

    if not os.path.exists('stock_dfs'):
        os.makedirs('stock_dfs')

    start = dt.datetime(2010,1,1)
    end = dt.datetime.now()

    for ticker in tickers:
        try:
            print(ticker)
            if not os.path.exists('stocks_dfs/{}.csv'.format(ticker)):
                df = pdr.DataReader(ticker, 'yahoo', start, end)
                df.to_csv('stock_dfs/{}.csv'.format(ticker))
            else:
                print('Already have {}'.format(ticker))
        except:
            print('Cannot obtain data for ' +ticker)
```

Comment: Because `3` is not a list. If you want to use it as a list, put `[]` around it.

Comment: How can I make my code handle this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `test` does not contain only iterable types.

The third element is an int (3).

The inner loop will try to execute:

```
for x in 3:
```

which fails because 3 is not iterable.

You need to either check if the element is iterable like:

```
test = [[0], [1,2], 3]
for sub_list in test:
    try:
        iterator = iter(sub_list)
        for x in sub_list:
            print(x)
    except TypeError as te:
        print(sub_list)
```

or just make sure every element is iterable:

```
test = [[0], [1,2], [3]]
for sub_list in test:
    for x in sub_list:
        print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to the previous rep, you can also check type of element

```py
for sub_list in test:
  if isinstance(list, sub_list):
    for e in sub_list:
      print(e)
  else:
    print(e)
```

This only handles 2-level nested lists though. If your list is nested further, it's better to write recursive or iterative function instead.